# Adding metadata to iTunes compatible video file using AVFoundation without transcoding

Tags: macos, video, avfoundation, metadata, quicktime

Apple has just reject an update of a macOS application of mine because it uses a QTKit based command line executable in order to modify the video metadata embedded in file.

It seems that Quicktime APIs are no longer allowed but I really can't find a suitable replacement. To my knowledge you can't change the AVAsset metadata property (it's readonly) so the only way to modify the data is actually exporting a new video with the new metadata and deleting the former file. That's insane! My app can't afford that waste of time. The method I'm using till now just embed the new metadata into the file instantly.

Can anybody confirm that it is not possible to do that using AVFoundation? Is there any other alternative I could use?

Comment: Have you tried this with `AVExportSession`? https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avassetexportsession/export_preset_name_for_pass_through

Comment: That will avoid transcoding but still copy the entire file.